# why bundling doesn't work but when I declare it explicitly, it works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I wonder why `bundling` doesn't work. Here is my scenario. I use `foundation` framework for my front-end. Now, I include `foundation.js`, `foundation.magellan.js`. It works fine if I declare it like this.

`<script src="~/Scripts/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/foundation.magellan.js"></script>`

`<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>`

And this is what it renders:
[image]

But then I tried something like, (this doesn't work)

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/foundationjs").Include("~/Scripts/foundation.js"));`
`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/foundationsupport").Include("~/Scripts/foundation.magellan.js"));`

And then render then like this:

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foundationjs")`
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foundationsupport")`

`<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>`

And this is what it renders:
[image]

I tried to look if it returns a 404 error but it didn't. I tried clicking the button which clearly didn't work. How can I resolve this using bundling?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This could be a lot of things. Check your console for JavaScript errors. Also, post the *rendered* HTML for those scripts, i.e. the actual HTML on page that calls them.

Comment: Updated my question. And I checked the console and no error found.

Comment: They're different screenshot. Yea exactly, me too. Don't even have a clue why it didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. I saw the slight difference. It appears you're running locally, which means bundling doesn't actually *do* anything. The referenced scripts just get dumped to the page as is, as the screenshot indicates. That means, that bundling is not the issue here. The issue is the difference between `foundation.js` and `foundation.min.js`, as that's the only difference between the working solution and the failing one.

Comment: Perhaps try getting fresh copies of the files from the Foundation site and replace them.

Comment: Even tried that one but still didn't work. Anyhow, thanks mate. I guess I'll just have to move on to the project. Then come back to this if I have more time.

Comment: Yep. Very weird. Normally you see this in reverse, where the normal script works fine and minified version is borked. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: No, no, no. It's okay. It really helped me a lot. Thanks for pointing out the `foundation.min.js` and `foundation.js` didn't noticed that. And also for pointing out that I'm running locally. Really new to asp.net mvc though.

Comment: Do you have a unminified version of foundation.js? Put it in there next to the min'd version. If you don;t have one, take min'd version and copy it into the same directory without the .min part. If you are not running with optimizations min files are ignored.

Comment: Yes. I have what you requested but still. Don't know why it didn't work.